# Java method to return random element of array of different types

Tags: java, arrays, random

I would like to pass different arrays of changing parameter types at different times into a method/function of which randomly returns one element, however am extremely struggling to do so using Java.

I have attempted to do so using the following code:

```
public int rndInx(Array theArray) {
    theArray = theArray[(int)(Math.random() * theArray.length)];
    return theArray;

}
```

However, Eclipse draws attention to errors; *length not being resolved* and the *type of expression must be an array type*. I assume one cause of the issue is the returnType, however I'm unsure what type would accept a range of returnTypes. I am aware that the syntax is probably extremely wrong too since I've only recently began to learn Java :(

For example, if I was to pass an array containing integers, then one random integer element would be returned - and if I was to pass an array containing strings etc. than one random element from the array in question would be returned.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think you could return an object of type `Array` from a method with an `int` return type? How is selecting one element from the array and assigning it to a variable (parameter!) of an array type meant to work? And why do you try to use `Array` instead of the actualy array syntax which is `Xxx[]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the steps to achieve your end goal.

1. overload the method `rndInx` for `int[]` parameter, `double[]`, `long[]` and so forth for however many primitive types you need to consider.
2. create a generic method for reference types

here is a hint for the generic method:

```
public <T> T rndInx(T[] theArray) {
     return theArray[....]; // return the element at a random index
}
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks. Is there a simple way to explain the generic method. I find the syntax a little confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generic method:

```
public <T> T rndInx(T[] array) {
    int index = (int)(Math.random() * array.length);
    return array[];
}
```

But this won't work for primitive arrays. If you must accept primitive arrays, you'll have to use reflection and hope the caller has the right type:

```
public <T> T rndInx(Object array) {
    int index = (int)(Math.random() * Array.getLength(array));
    return (T)Array.get(array, index);
}
```

Or return `Object` and let the caller do the casting.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting the error `Array can not be resolved`. Must I import something?

Comment: @LearningToPython Yes: `java.lang.reflect.Array`.

Comment: Okay, Perfect. May I also ask what makes this solution 'generic'. I don't particular understand what <T> does in this case.

Comment: @LearningToPython It's a lot to explain if you're completely unfamiliar. Maybe start with the [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to use generics, e.g. like this:

```
public <T> T selectOneRandomly(T[] array) {
  return array[(int)(Math.random() * array.length)];
}
```

This should work for anything except primitives like `int`, `double` etc.
For those you'd either have to provide special methods via overloads (e.g. `int selectOneRandomly(int[] array)`)  or convert the arrays of primitives to arrays of wrapper types (i.e. `int[]` to `Integer[]`) before passing the converted arrays to your method.